# Why are random generated sequences of numbers the same for different class instances?

Tags: python, random, numbers, sequence, seed

I've been trying to generate different dictionary structures (pertaining to different class instances in Python) filled with random number values between [0, 1). The keys of the dictionary are not that the important. But, the main problem is that when I try and generate the dictionaries with the random values, they all come up as the same sequence:

```
{'p0': 0.8834439890229875, 'p1': 0.4542011548977558, 'd0': 0.041855079212439805, 'c0': 0.30179244567633823, 'c1': 0.026356543619428408, 'c2': 0.24603169392476631}
{'p0': 0.8834439890229875, 'p1': 0.4542011548977558, 'd0': 0.041855079212439805, 'c0': 0.30179244567633823, 'c1': 0.026356543619428408, 'c2': 0.24603169392476631}
{'p0': 0.8834439890229875, 'p1': 0.4542011548977558, 'd0': 0.041855079212439805, 'c0': 0.30179244567633823, 'c1': 0.026356543619428408, 'c2': 0.24603169392476631}
```

**Code:**

```
''' Individual Class '''

from random import Random

class Individual:

        chromosome = {} #The chromosome of an individual is a random generated dictionary.
        randomInstance = Random(datetime.now())

        def __init__(self, numP, numD, numC):
                self.randomInstance.seed()
                for i in range(numP):
                        plant = "p"
                        plant += str(i)
                        self.chromosome[plant] = self.randomInstance.random()

                for j in range(numD):
                        plant = "d"
                        plant += str(j)
                        self.chromosome[plant] = self.randomInstance.random()

                for k in range(numC):
                        plant = "c"
                        plant += str(k)
                        self.chromosome[plant] = self.randomInstance.random()

def main():

        list = []
        for i in range(4):
                inst = Individual(2, 1 ,3)
                list.append(inst.chromosome)

        print(list)
```

I'm trying to get a different sequence per class instance.

Hope someone can help. Thank you all.

Comment: Don’t name a variable `list`. Also I’m pretty sure they’re all sharing the same seed, which is why you get the same exact numbers.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That question has the exact same naming mistake too lol

Comment: Is that because of the list() method?

Comment: It does answer my question. Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `chromosome` and `randomInstance` as class attributes so they're shared across all instances of the class.  If you want it per instance then initialize them as class properties in the **init** instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue. Cheers.